# Rebus #21 needs unlocking

Tags: rebus

This is a 1-word singular noun.

[image]

Comment: It didn't appear on my screen before, only after it was done

Comment: "only after it was done  ?

Comment: Wordster, you're posting something like one rebus per hour at the moment. That's a bit much, I think. One a day would be a better rate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> hydrant! hydra + ant = hydrant

Comment: Bingo!  You got it!